# Python Numpy FFT fast fourier transform - weird results

Tags: python, numpy, transform, fft

I am trying to get the phase distribution of a 2D aperture using FFT.
The input is a circle, where everything inside the circle has value 1, outside it has value 0.
In order to make a good transform, I use an input array that is 200x as large as the radius of the circle, and make a 5000x5000 grid out of it. This ensures that the circle is actually circular and there is enough room around in order that no Nyquist things happen.

I need to 2D Fourier transform the aperture and then calculate the phase of the Fourier transform at every point.
The function I use for creating the input (aperture):
[creating the input aperture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45rsi.png)

Next do the numpy fft2 2D fourier transform:
[Fourier transforming aperture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwGRn.png)

And the result of this is a 2D complex array (as expected!), BUT with the imaginary parts so much much much smaller than the real parts (17 orders of magnitude difference imaginary parts ~10E-17).
This is not expected and most probably wrong. What went wrong?

Comment: Please kindly extract the code from images linked and properly format it in your question, so the community can help you more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

The FFT phase result of a perfectly symmetric input is zero, e.g. a strictly real result, thus atan2(Im,Re) == 0 , (imaginary components all zero, except for rounding noise).

(even symmetry with respect to (0,0) circularly, or to (n/2,n/2))

The phase will become non-zero (thus a non-zero imaginary component in the FFT result) when the input is moved off center or otherwise made non-symmetric.

Comment: Thank you!
This seems to prove it, right?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184332/fourier-transform-of-even-odd-function

Comment: on second thought, what you said is only valid for 1D transforms, not 2D

Comment: True for any dimension, due to symmetry of the real part of the basis functions of the transform

Comment: not according to this:
https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~wjh/teaching/Fourier/documents/symmetry.pdf
"In this case [2D] the symmetry properties are more complicated, however we say that the real part
is symmetric and the imaginary part is anti-symmetric"